# Merge two objects List in Java

Tags: list, java-8, java-stream, equals, hashcode

How to merge two user list, if user is common merge its attribute.

I have two user lists, getting first list from DB and second from web service, if their firstname and lastname are same then user merge attribute and return combined list.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

 class User {
     String firstName;
     String lastName;
     Integer count;
     Integer marks;
     String status;

     @Override
     public boolean equals(Object o) {
         if (this == o) return true;
         if (!(o instanceof User)) return false;
         User user = (User) o;
         return Objects.equals(firstName, user.firstName) &&
                 Objects.equals(lastName, user.lastName);
     }

     @Override
     public int hashCode() {
         return Objects.hash(firstName, lastName);
     }

    //constructor getter setter....

 }




 public class MainTest {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         List<User> source1 = List.of(new User("A", "A", 1, 0, null),
                 new User("B", "B", 2, 0, null),
                 new User("C", "C", 3, 0, null));

         List<User> source2 = List.of(new User("A", "A", 0, 10, "FAIL"),
                 new User("B", "B", 0, 20, "FAIL"),
                 new User("D", "D", 0, 30, "PASS"));


         List<User> combinedExpectedList = List.of(new User("A", "A", 1, 10, "FAIL"),
                 new User("B", "B", 2, 20, "FAIL"),
                 new User("C", "C", 3, 0, null),
                 new User("D", "D", 0, 30, "PASS"));

         //List<User> userList3= Stream.concat(source1.stream(), source2.stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());//Adding 4 records but marks and status not copied
         //BeanUtils.copyProperties(model2, model1); - can't user don't have library

         for (User t : source2) {
             for (User s : source1) {
                 if (t.getFirstName().equals(s.getFirstName()) && t.getLastName().equals(s.getLastName())) {
                     t.setCount(s.getCount());
                 }
             }
         }// Not adding record with firstName=C and LastName=C

         System.out.println(combinedExpectedList.equals(source2));
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to retain non zero marks and non null status elements, you can not directly use distinct. You can use `Collectors.toMap` as below,

```
List<User> userList3 = Stream.concat(source1.stream(), source2.stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.firstName + e.lastName, e -> e,
                        (User u1, User u2) -> {
                            if (u1.marks == 0)
                                u1.marks = u2.marks;
                            if (u1.status == null)
                                u1.status = u2.status;
                            return u1;
                        })).values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that you may need to reorder elements.

Comment: 'if's can be change to something like this: `Stream.of(u1.marks, u2.marks).filter(val -> val != 0).findFirst().ifPresent(val -> u1.marks = val)` and `Stream.of(u1.status, u2.status).filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst().ifPresent(val -> u1.status  = val)`

Comment: @lczapski nice suggestion but I feel, in this case, `if` is more concise and readable.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60318761/11733759) but here 'User' within source list remains unchanged:

```java
List<User> values = new ArrayList<>(Stream.concat(source1.stream(), source2.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.firstName + e.lastName, Function.identity(),
                (User u1, User u2) ->
                        new User(u1.firstName, u1.lastName, u1.count,
                                (u1.marks == 0) ? u2.marks : u1.marks,
                                (u1.status == null) ? u2.status : u1.status
                        )
        )).values());
```